# Output network switch configuration txt to csv multiple columns

Tags: python, csv

I have a text file that is switch interface configuration. I would like to pull out a few lines from the configuration and output them to a csv. Any help would be appreciated

My code below outputs each letter into its own column. Image of csv after running: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwE1s.png

```
import csv
import sys

txt_file = r"results.txt"
csv_file = r"testBook.csv"

csv_out = open(csv_file, "w")

in_txt = open(txt_file, "r")

out_csv = csv.writer(csv_out)


arr = []

for line in in_txt:
    arr.append(line)


out_csv.writerows(arr)




csv_out.close()
```

Text file used:

File name: 172.16.0.11.txt

`interface 0/1
traffic-shape 5
description 'testname'
switchport mode trunk
switchport trunk native vlan 20
switchport trunk allowed vlan 2-3,20,52
ip access-group mbps25 in 1
exit
interface 0/2
description 'testname5'
switchport mode trunk
exit
interface 0/3
speed 1000 full-duplex
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan 2
exit`

I would like to get an output of something close to this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T08QU.png

Breakdown:

The Switch IP column would populate from the file name 172.16.0.11.txt

The interface column would populate from the interface number

The description column would populate from that interfaces information (if it has a description)

The traffic-shape column would populate from that interfaces information (if it has a traffic-shape)

The ip access-group column would populate from that interfaces information (if it has a access-group)

Comment: You should first show what you have tried. Currently this is a *give me the code* question which is not well received on this site. Please read [ask] to know how to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**:  ... pull out a few lines from the configuration and output them to a csv

```
#                  keyword : (fieldname, from, to)
D = OrderedDict([('_', ('Switch IP',)),
                 ('interface',('Interface', 1, 2)),
                 ('description', ('Description', 1, 2)),
                 ('traffic-shape', ('Traffic-Shape', 1, 2)),
                 ('ip',  ('IP Access-Group', 2, 5))])

with open(filename + ".txt") as txt_file, open('testBook.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    # Build Fieldnames from D
    fieldnames = [D[d][0] for d in D]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    # Init CSV Record
    record = {fieldnames[0]: filename}

    while True:
        line = txt_file.readline()[:-1]
        if not line: break

        words = line.split()

        # Write CSV Record if 'exit'
        if words[0] == 'exit':
            writer.writerow(record)
            record = {fieldnames[0]:filename}
        else:
            try:
                # Get Keyword Setting from D
                k = D[words[0]]
                # Update CSV Record 'fieldname' with Slice(from,to)
                record[k[0]] = ' '.join(words[k[1]:k[2]])
            except:
                pass
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> Switch IP,Interface,Description,Traffic-Shape,IP Access-Group
> 172.16.0.11,0/1,'testname',5,mbps25 in 1
> 172.16.0.11,0/2,'testname5',,
> 172.16.0.11,0/3,,,
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***